# Is there a name for "map head . group"?

Tags: haskell, naming

The function `map head . group :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` collapses equal adjacent values to a single value.
As opposed to `nub`, it does not remove *all* following equal values.

For example:

```
nub                [1,1,2,1] == [1,2]
(map head . group) [1,1,2,1] == [1,2,1]
```

I couldn't find this function in the standard library. Is there an established name for it?

Comment: I don't think it has a name but I'd probably call it `squash`.

Comment: There's a POSIX tool named "uniq" that does this for lines of a text file.  Does that count as an "established name"?

Comment: @melpomene I like it :-)

Comment: @jwodder there is a function called `uniq` in MissingH which does something slightly different. But POSIX certainly preceded it and it's nice and short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a function is not available in the standard libraries. A quick [Hoogle query](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq+a+%3D%3E+%5Ba%5D-%3E%5Ba%5D) reveals that the only other function in the core libraries with the type of `Eq a => [a] -> [a]` is `nub`.